# How to convert SQL statement to an expression in SSIS package

Tags: sql, sql-server, ssis

I have the following SQL statement:

```
DATEADD( DAY, 0 - (DATEPART(weekday, GETDATE()) % 7), GETDATE() )
```

Which returns:

```
2014-04-19 10:10:02.757
```

How can I change the SQL statement to use in SSIS package expression to get the last saturday's date in this format:

```
4-19-2014
```

When I tried the sql statement in expression builder, I get the following error:

[image]

Comment: Put day in double quotes:  `DATEADD( "DAY"...`  Double quotes around those type of arguments is going to be very standard in SSIS.  So your `WEEKDAY` will need the quotes as well.

Comment: Thank you for the response, but now I get a `Cannot convert 'system.datetime' to 'system.string'` error.

Comment: @SiKni8 - May I ask why you are saving it in an expression ?

Comment: Ohhhh, good question. Because the filename will be the date, so for example, it will be mm-dd-yyyy-.xlsx and it changes every saturday.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try using the following for the expression:

```
(DT_WSTR,10)(RIGHT("0" + (DT_STR, 2, 1252) DATEPART("mm" , DATEADD("D", 0 - (DATEPART("weekday", GETDATE()) % 7) , GETDATE())), 1) + "-" + RIGHT("0" + (DT_STR, 2, 1252) DATEPART("dd" , DATEADD("D", 0 - (DATEPART("weekday", GETDATE()) % 7) , GETDATE())), 2) + "-" + RIGHT("0" + (DT_STR, 4, 1252) DATEPART("yy" , DATEADD("D", 0 - (DATEPART("weekday", GETDATE()) % 7) , GETDATE())), 4))
```

Comment: I get a `A truncation occurred during the evaluation of the expression` error

Comment: Sorry, miscounted the number of characters.  I've updated the answer

Comment: `(DT_WSTR,10)(RIGHT("0" + (DT_STR, 2, 1252) DATEPART("mm" , DATEADD("D", 0 - (DATEPART("weekday", GETDATE()) % 7) , GETDATE())), 2) + "-" + RIGHT("0" + (DT_STR, 4, 1252) DATEPART("yy" , DATEADD("D", 0 - (DATEPART("weekday", GETDATE()) % 7) , GETDATE())), 2))` How can I modify it to give me the number for last month instead of current month?